# Inequality of expected value

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be i.i.d. with $E|X_i|=\infty$ and $a_n$ be a sequence of positive numbers with $a_n/n$ increasing. Why the inequality $\sum^n_{i=1} E(|X_i|; |X_i|<a_i) \leq a_N + E(|X|; a_N \leq |X| < a_n)$ holds for any fixed $N$? Here $E(X;C)=\int_C XdP$.

This is the very last part of the proof of theorem 2.5.13 from Durrett, Probability Theory and Examples.

Comment: Isn't $a_N \geq a_n$? In that case, the second term on the RHS would be $0$?

Comment: @sudeep5221 The sequence $a_n$ is increasing. So if for any fixed $N$ means one can choose $N\geq n$, then I believe you are right. But does the ineqaulity hold in this case?

Comment: Something wrong here. $X_i=\frac1  2, a_n=n$ and $n>2N$ leads to a contradiction.

Comment: @geetha290krm Sorry, I omitted the condition $E|X_i|=\infty$. I thought it was unnecessary for this part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a typo in Durrett's proof that led you to write a generally incorrect inequality. The correct upper bound should be $\sum^n_{i=1} E(|X_i|; |X_i|<a_i) \leq na_N + E(|X|; a_N \leq |X| < a_n)$. Durret has an extra $n$ in a previous inequality that is being carried over.

Getting there is almost immediate: $1(|X_i| < a_i) = 1(|X_i| < a_N) + 1(a_N \leq |X_i| < a_i)$, so $$ \sum^n_{i=1} E(|X_i|; |X_i|<a_i) \leq \sum^n_{i=1} E(|X_i|; |X_i|<a_N) + \sum^n_{i=1} E(|X_i|; a_N \leq |X_i|<a_N) \leq n a_N + \sum^n_{i=1} E(|X_i|; a_N \leq |X_i|<a_N) $$

The result is originally due to Feller (1946) and correctly derived there.